# Disconnected Raid 0 drives now cannot see drives

Tags: raid-0

I stupidly disconnected a RAID 0 drive while checking the information on the HDD (while it was turned on) and was not able view the drive again in disk manager. I then disconnected all the 4 drives on my server, while it was turned on and plugged them back up again.

Now I cannot see the two drives in RAID 0. I am hoping that they are hidden and have not been wiped as the drives are fine and in perfect working order.

Does anybody know how I can get my missing RAID 0 drives to show again?

I'm using a Dell PowerEdge T-300 with PERC6i RAID controller.

Thanks